# Drools rule: Checking if a String contains any String in a collection

Tags: drools

Is there a way in drools to check if a string input contains any of the following Strings in a collection?

For example: 
String input="How now brown cow."
List stringList=[blue, brown, green, orange]

I want to be able to say:
If input.contains(any String in stringList)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah figured it out!

```
If
        $x : String() from $s.stringList;
        $s : Object(input.contains($x)); Then....
```